# Building squid-cache on OS-X Mavericks

Tags: compilation, osx-mavericks, squid

I'm attempting to build squid-cache (squid-3.4.2) on Mavericks (10.9.1) with the following configure based on the SquidMan FAQ:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/squid --disable-eui CFLAGS=-mmacosx-version-min=10.9 --enable-pf-transparent
```

The build fails at the kerberos helpers:

```
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../../.. -I../../../include -I../../../lib -I../../../src -I../../../include   -I../../../libltdl -I../../.. -I../../../include -I../../../lib -I../../../src -I../../../include   -I../../../libltdl -I.  -Werror -Qunused-arguments  -D_REENTRANT -g -O2 -march=native -std=c++0x -MT support_krb5.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/support_krb5.Tpo -c -o support_krb5.o support_krb5.cc
support_krb5.cc:47:13: error: 'krb5_cc_destroy' is deprecated: use GSS.framework
      [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            krb5_cc_destroy(kparam.context, kparam.cc);
            ^
/usr/include/krb5/krb5.h:1296:1: note: 'krb5_cc_destroy' declared here
krb5_cc_destroy (krb5_context context, krb5_ccache cache) KERBEROS_APPLE_DEPRECATED("use GSS.framework");
^
support_krb5.cc:48:9: error: 'krb5_free_context' is deprecated: use GSS.framework
      [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        krb5_free_context(kparam.context);
        ^
/usr/include/krb5/krb5.h:1456:20: note: 'krb5_free_context' declared here
void KRB5_CALLCONV krb5_free_context
                   ^
support_krb5.cc:80:12: error: 'krb5_init_context' is deprecated: use GSS.framework
      [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    code = krb5_init_context(&kparam.context);
           ^
/usr/include/krb5/krb5.h:1452:31: note: 'krb5_init_context' declared here
krb5_error_code KRB5_CALLCONV krb5_init_context
                              ^
support_krb5.cc:91:5: error: 'krb5_kt_default_name' is deprecated: use GSS.framework
      [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    krb5_kt_default_name(kparam.context, buf, KT_PATH_MAX);
    ^
/usr/include/krb5/krb5.h:1702:31: note: 'krb5_kt_default_name' declared here
krb5_error_code KRB5_CALLCONV krb5_kt_default_name
                              ^
support_krb5.cc:98:12: error: 'krb5_kt_resolve' is deprecated: use GSS.framework
      [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    code = krb5_kt_resolve(kparam.context, keytab_name, &keytab);
           ^
/usr/include/krb5/krb5.h:1698:31: note: 'krb5_kt_resolve' declared here
krb5_error_code KRB5_CALLCONV krb5_kt_resolve
                              ^
support_krb5.cc:104:12: error: 'krb5_kt_start_seq_get' is deprecated: use GSS.framework
      [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    code = krb5_kt_start_seq_get(kparam.context, keytab, &cursor);
           ^
/usr/include/krb5/krb5.h:1435:1: note: 'krb5_kt_start_seq_get' declared here
krb5_kt_start_seq_get(krb5_context context, krb5_keytab keytab,
^
support_krb5.cc:113:20: error: 'krb5_kt_next_entry' is deprecated: use GSS.framework
      [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    while ((code = krb5_kt_next_entry(kparam.context, keytab, &entry, &cursor)) == 0) {
                   ^
/usr/include/krb5/krb5.h:1438:1: note: 'krb5_kt_next_entry' declared here
krb5_kt_next_entry(krb5_context context, krb5_keytab keytab,
^
support_krb5.cc:117:9: error: 'krb5_copy_principal' is deprecated: use GSS.framework
      [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        krb5_copy_principal(kparam.context, entry.principal, &principal_list[nprinc++]);
        ^
/usr/include/krb5/krb5.h:1633:31: note: 'krb5_copy_principal' declared here
krb5_error_code KRB5_CALLCONV krb5_copy_principal
                              ^
support_krb5.cc:129:20: error: 'krb5_unparse_name' is deprecated: use GSS.framework
      [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            code = krb5_unparse_name(kparam.context, entry.principal, &principal_name);
                   ^
/usr/include/krb5/krb5.h:1561:31: note: 'krb5_unparse_name' declared here
krb5_error_code KRB5_CALLCONV krb5_unparse_name
                              ^
support_krb5.cc:140:16: error: 'krb5_free_keytab_entry_contents' is deprecated: use GSS.framework
      [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        code = krb5_free_keytab_entry_contents(kparam.context, &entry);
               ^
/usr/include/krb5/krb5.h:1709:31: note: 'krb5_free_keytab_entry_contents' declared here
krb5_error_code KRB5_CALLCONV krb5_free_keytab_entry_contents
                              ^
support_krb5.cc:156:12: error: 'krb5_kt_end_seq_get' is deprecated: use GSS.framework
      [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    code = krb5_kt_end_seq_get(kparam.context, keytab, &cursor);
           ^
/usr/include/krb5/krb5.h:1441:1: note: 'krb5_kt_end_seq_get' declared here
krb5_kt_end_seq_get(krb5_context context, krb5_keytab keytab,
^
support_krb5.cc:175:12: error: 'krb5_cc_resolve' is deprecated: use GSS.framework
      [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    code = krb5_cc_resolve(kparam.context, mem_cache, &kparam.cc);
           ^
/usr/include/krb5/krb5.h:1728:31: note: 'krb5_cc_resolve' declared here
krb5_error_code KRB5_CALLCONV krb5_cc_resolve
                              ^
support_krb5.cc:196:20: error: 'krb5_unparse_name' is deprecated: use GSS.framework
      [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            code = krb5_unparse_name(kparam.context, principal_list[i], &principal_name);
                   ^
/usr/include/krb5/krb5.h:1561:31: note: 'krb5_unparse_name' declared here
krb5_error_code KRB5_CALLCONV krb5_unparse_name
                              ^
support_krb5.cc:204:20: error: 'krb5_get_init_creds_keytab' is deprecated: use GSS.framework
      [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            code = krb5_get_init_creds_keytab(kparam.context, creds, principal_list[i], keytab, 0, NULL, NULL);
                   ^
/usr/include/krb5/krb5.h:2337:1: note: 'krb5_get_init_creds_keytab' declared here
krb5_get_init_creds_keytab
^
support_krb5.cc:217:20: error: 'krb5_cc_initialize' is deprecated: use GSS.framework
      [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            code = krb5_cc_initialize(kparam.context, kparam.cc, principal_list[i]);
                   ^
/usr/include/krb5/krb5.h:1292:1: note: 'krb5_cc_initialize' declared here
krb5_cc_initialize(krb5_context context, krb5_ccache cache,
^
support_krb5.cc:222:20: error: 'krb5_cc_store_cred' is deprecated: use GSS.framework
      [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            code = krb5_cc_store_cred(kparam.context, kparam.cc, creds);
                   ^
/usr/include/krb5/krb5.h:1302:1: note: 'krb5_cc_store_cred' declared here
krb5_cc_store_cred (krb5_context context, krb5_ccache cache,
^
support_krb5.cc:228:17: error: 'krb5_free_principal' is deprecated: use GSS.framework
      [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                krb5_free_principal(kparam.context, creds->server);
                ^
/usr/include/krb5/krb5.h:1760:20: note: 'krb5_free_principal' declared here
void KRB5_CALLCONV krb5_free_principal
                   ^
support_krb5.cc:236:20: error: 'krb5_parse_name' is deprecated: use GSS.framework
      [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            code = krb5_parse_name(kparam.context, service, &creds->server);
                   ^
/usr/include/krb5/krb5.h:1549:31: note: 'krb5_parse_name' declared here
krb5_error_code KRB5_CALLCONV krb5_parse_name
                              ^
support_krb5.cc:242:20: error: 'krb5_get_credentials' is deprecated: use GSS.framework
      [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            code = krb5_get_credentials(kparam.context, 0, kparam.cc, creds, &tgt_creds);
                   ^
/usr/include/krb5/krb5.h:1486:31: note: 'krb5_get_credentials' declared here
krb5_error_code KRB5_CALLCONV krb5_get_credentials
                              ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make[4]: *** [support_krb5.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I'm not quite sure how to resolve this issue.

My initial use of squid does not need kerberos, so after some configuration mining I found that this flag will turn off that part of the build:

```
--with-krb5-config=no
```

But then I end up with errors during the ldap helper build. (which I also don't need)...and then manually editing Makefiles becomes a deep rabbit hole which still results in build errors.

I would like to get this to build correctly "as-is" without substantial build changes.  There seems to be very little knowledge online to help with this.

Does anyone have experience building this on os-x Mavericks? and, if-so, what are the changes I need?

Comment: Just found that Homebrew has a slightly older version of squid (3.3.11) that does compile on Mavericks.  However, changing the --enable-ipf-transparent to --enable-pf-tranparent breaks the build.  There appears to be a ticket for this, but has had no action: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/23243

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Successfully compiled with :

```
--prefix=/usr/local 
--disable-auth
--with-krb5-config=no
--disable-external-acl-helpers
--disable-eui
```

**tested** : ok

**My hardware**:

- MacBoo: Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) 2.5Ghz i7
- squid version 3.5.6
- OSX 10.10.04
- Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)

Answer (score 2):

On OSX 10.9.3, the following worked for me

```
./configure CPPFLAGS='-Wno-error=deprecated-declarations' LDFLAGS='-lresolv'
```

Comment: This also works on yosemite to suppress ldap deprecation warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if this helps, because I'm still on MAC OS 10.7 (Lion). `make` does not complain about kerberos, but also stops with some errors regarding LDAP. After removing the lines

```
#define HAVE_LDAP_H 1
BUILD_HELPER="kerberos_ldap_group"
#define HAVE_MOZLDAP_LDAP_H 1
$as_echo "#define HAVE_LDAP 1" >>confdefs.h
$as_echo "#define HAVE_OPENLDAP 1" >>confdefs.h
$as_echo "#define HAVE_SUN_LDAP_SDK 1" >>confdefs.h
$as_echo "#define HAVE_MOZILLA_LDAP_SDK 1" >>confdefs.h
$as_echo "#define HAVE_LDAP_REBINDPROC_CALLBACK 1" >>confdefs.h
$as_echo "#define HAVE_LDAP_REBIND_PROC 1" >>confdefs.h
$as_echo "#define HAVE_LDAP_REBIND_FUNCTION 1" >>confdefs.h
$as_echo "#define HAVE_LDAP_SCOPE_DEFAULT 1" >>confdefs.h
$as_echo "#define HAVE_LDAP_URL_LUD_SCHEME 1" >>confdefs.h
$as_echo "#define HAVE_LDAPSSL_CLIENT_INIT 1" >>confdefs.h
$as_echo "#define HAVE_LDAP_URL_DESC2STR 1" >>confdefs.h
$as_echo "#define HAVE_LDAP_URL_PARSE 1" >>confdefs.h
$as_echo "#define HAVE_LDAP_START_TLS_S 1" >>confdefs.h
```

from the `configure` script and running it without any command line options, squid-3.4.2 compiled. It worked for me, but it's still a hack. I guess the proper way to solve the problem is to use the `--enable-auth-basic`, `--enable-auth-digest` and `--enable-external-acl-helpers` options for `configure` and list all helpers except LDAP (or at least all you need).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the kerberos is being used if you plan for domain level authentication (e.g. AD / LDAP). You can disable the helper and authentication method with the following options 
`disable-auth --disable-external-acl-helper`

Answer (score -1):

This is an open known bug in Squid right now:
http://bugs.squid-cache.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4023

I tried the following work around to bypass these external ACL modules as follows.

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/squid --with-krb5-config=no
--disable-external-acl-helpers
```

I still ran into other issues:
http://bugs.squid-cache.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4043